# Matrix Inversion GPU MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, gpu, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I'm looking for a way to find the pseudo-inverse of a matrix so it can be done on the GPU.
SVD/QR are difficult to parallelize and are not supported but MATLAB's GPU, but it seems that LU, though can be run in parallel is not supported by MATLAB's GPU as well. I compared performance and it seems to be slower than running on a single core CPU.

I am looking for a pseudo inverse (or even a regular inverse for square matrices) that I can use. According to Matlab, using mldivide () performs Gauss elimination which is applicable for GPUs.

I tried using A\I but unfortunately it does not run efficiently on GPUs.

Does anyone can direct me to an optimized code for parallel LU or Gaussian elimination?

I heard of the MAGMA package, but it seems a lot of work to install and to compile and I really need this simple thing.

A C++ code is also welcome.

Thanks,
Gil

Comment: Your question sounds confusing... `A \ eye(size(A, 1))` is in general not the Moore Penrose pseudo inverse of `A`; moreover MATLAB has some support for SVD on gpu. In order to give you a sensible answer we  will need more information: size, rank, and other properties of `A`, and exactly what type of generalized inverse you are interested in. Generalized inverses are seldom used in linear algebra: stating tha actual problem you are trying to solve by the computation of a generalized inverse of `A` could also be useful.

Comment: afaik, MATLAB uses the MAGMA package for some of its operations on the GPU. Here is a list of the functions that `gpuArray` supports: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/using-gpuarray.html#bsloua3-1

Comment: @Gil: `pinv(A)` is [similar to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore-Penrose_pseudoinverse#Singular_value_decomposition_.28SVD.29) `V*diag(1./diag(S))*U'` where `[U,S,V] = svd(A)`. But as was said, you rarely need the inverse of a matrix itself, `mldivide`/`mrdivide` are usually what you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MATLAB R2013a, LU, QR and SVD are all supported on the gpu through gpuArray. There's a list of supported functions here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/using-gpuarray.html#bsloua3-1 . The linear algebra functions of gpuArray are all implemented using MAGMA.

`A\b` can run efficiently on the GPU, see this example: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/examples/benchmarking-a-b-on-the-gpu.html . As the problem size increases, you can expect a decently powerful GPU (e.g. Tesla) to run up to 5 times faster than the CPU.

Comment: Thanks. I tried A\eye on GPU and it was actually slower. Perhaps it was because I'm using 2012b. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't expect a large performance difference for `A\b` between R2012b and R2013a - your problem size / GPU hardware are much more likely to be important.

Answer (score 0):

This article [MATRIX INVERSION SPEED UP WITH CUDA](http://upcommons.upc.edu/pfc/bitstream/2099.1/13182/1/PFC_Jorge_Soriano_Pinedo_-_Matrix_inversion_speed_up_with_CUDA.pdf) may help:

> ABSTRACT
>   In this project several mathematic algorithms are developed to obtain a matrix inversion method - that combines CUDA’s parallel architecture and MATLAB – which is actually faster than MATLAB’s built in inverse matrix function. This matrix inversion method is intended to be used for image reconstruction as a faster alternative to iterative methods with a comparable quality. The algorithms developed in this project are Gauss-Jordan elimination, Cholesky decomposition, Gaussian elimination and matrix multiplication.